# Php remove () in a function to make it easier to use

Tags: php

I am creating a little system which will allow users to extend the system with their own classes.

```
Class Core {
static $confArray;
static $extendArray;
protected static $instance;
public function read($name)
{
    return self::$confArray[$name];
}
public function put($name, $value)
{
    self::$confArray[$name] = $value;
}
public function extend($function, $handler, $args=null){

    self::$extendArray[$function] = new $handler($args);
}
public function __call($method, $args){
    return self::$extendArray[$method];
}
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
    {
        $object =__CLASS__;
        self::$instance= new $object;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
}
```

With That, now a user can come and register a simple extension from such a class:

```
class WorkersTest{
function isWorking($who){
    echo "$who is working";
}
function isNotWorking($who){
    echo "$who is not working";
}
}
```

To call the function (isworking/ isNotWorking), a the programmer needs to register the `test` class through:

```
Core::getInstance->extend("worker","WorkersTest");
```

Then it can now be called through:

```
Core::getInstance->worker()->isWorking("George");
```

This is working perfectly. My question is how i can remove the `()` in the call (dont worry why) and have:

```
Core::getInstance->worker->isWorking("George");
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the magic `__get()` method, just like `__call()`:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->$name();
}
```

Comment: You don't push arguments ... how would you do that with no parenthesis?

Comment: I get it now, you did not mention I had to use the `__set` method too

Comment: Well, you don't really have to ... but I don't know all of your implementation details. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding the magic __get() method to return what you need:

```
Class Core {

   // (...)

   public function __get($name) {
      if (isset( self::$extendArray[$function] )) {
         return $this->$name();
      }
      //if there is no function registered under named "$name"
      //throwing Exception is by design better, as @scragar suggested
      throw new Exception("No function registered under named {$name}");
      //return NULL;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest throwing an exception with the code he's got, otherwise he's going to run into a lot of "Call to a member function call_method() on a non-object" (or for 5.6 "Call to a member function call_method() on null")